# Assign MySQL user to multiple databases via CLI

Tags: mysql

I already searched for this but I cannot find what I'm exactly looking for.

Is there an command to assign one user in all databases in my Cpanel account?

What I found online is this:

```
GRANT permission ON database.table TO 'user'@'localhost',
```

But this will only grant permission to one specific database, not all databases in my localhost.

I have created like 100+ MySQL db, and 1 user. I would like to grant that 1 user ALL PRIVILEGES to all DBs in my server.

For example, if my DB username is bryan, and I have multiple databases, how can I assign bryan to all of that databases and granting bryan ALL PRIVILEGE.

Instead of going to cpanel and assigning it one at a time, there should be a faster way, specially if it's just the same user.

Like with the user "root", it has access to all DBs in my server. I want to create a new user with access similar to root.

Comment: What does ssh have to do with database privileges?

Comment: The access privileges on the database is not related to the method used for server accessing. Adjust user's account permissions and add needed privileges to needed databases. SSL provides secured connection to the **server** (not databases) only.

Comment: I mean via SSH/CLI. Command Line. O__O Like what MySQL command should I enter to assign/grant a user to a specific database. With the command GRANT permission ON database.table TO 'user'@'localhost', I can grant permission to just one database. But what if I have 100+ DBs and I want a DB user to have access to all those DBs in the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me stupidity, I think I found the answer to my own question here.
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/grant-permissions-to-a-mysql-user-on-linux-via-command-line/